# What is the best way to get report on free/used tablespaces

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

please consult me on - what is the best way to get report on free/used tablespaces in our database (Oracle) - (Tablespace Name, Free MB, Used MB)

May be Oracle has some utility giving report which i want?
Or if not, please consult/advice on other method.

With regards!

Answer (score 1):

Run the following code in SQL*Plus as a `sysdba` user (or a user with the `DBA` role or `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY`).  It is best to save it as an SQL file (e.g. `fs.sql`) and run it with `@fs`

It will report useful stuff for each tablespace including size, free Mb  %free and so on

```
COLUMN ts_name   FORMAT A25       HEADING "Tablespace"
COLUMN ts_size   FORMAT 999,999.9 HEADING "Size mb"
COLUMN ts_free   FORMAT 999,999.9 HEADING "Free Mb"
COLUMN pct_free  FORMAT 999.99    HEADING "% free"
COLUMN max_size  FORMAT 999,999.9 HEADING "Max Mb"
COLUMN frags     FORMAT 99,999    HEADING "Frags"
COLUMN largest   FORMAT 9,999.99  HEADING "Largest"
COLUMN smallest  FORMAT 9,999.99  HEADING "Smallest"
COLUMN average   FORMAT 9,999.99  HEADING "Average"
COLUMN dfiles    FORMAT 999       HEADING "DFs"
COLUMN ts_type   FORMAT A4        HEADING "Type"
COLUMN ex        FORMAT A2        HEADING "Ex"
COLUMN status    FORMAT A7        HEADING "Status"
COLUMN big       FORMAT A3        HEADING "Big"

SET PAGESIZE 9999
SET NULL 0

SELECT  SUBSTR(t.tablespace_name, 1, 25) AS ts_name,
    ts.ts_size,
    CASE WHEN(t.contents = 'TEMPORARY') THEN
        ts.ts_size - NVL(te.free_space, 0)
    ELSE
        NVL(te.free_space, 0)
    END AS ts_free,
    CASE WHEN(t.contents = 'TEMPORARY') THEN
        100-(100*NVL(te.free_space, 0)/ts_size)
    ELSE
        100*NVL(te.free_space, 0)/ts_size
    END AS pct_free,
    ts.max_size,
    NVL(te.fragments, 0) AS frags,
    NVL(te.largest, 0) AS largest,
    NVL(te.smallest, 0) AS smallest,
    NVL(te.average, 0) AS average,
    ts.dfiles,
    SUBSTR(t.contents, 1, 4) AS ts_type,
    SUBSTR(t.extent_management,1 ,1) AS ex,
    t.status,
    DECODE(t.bigfile, 'NO', 'No', 'Yes') AS big
FROM
    dba_tablespaces t
LEFT
JOIN   (SELECT  tablespace_name,
        SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 AS ts_size,
        COUNT(bytes) AS dfiles,
        SUM(DECODE(maxbytes, 0, bytes, maxbytes))/1024/1024 AS max_size
    FROM
        dba_data_files
    GROUP
    BY  tablespace_name
    UNION
    SELECT  tablespace_name,
        SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 AS ts_size,
        COUNT(bytes) AS dfiles,
        SUM(DECODE(maxbytes, 0, bytes, maxbytes))/1024/1024 AS max_size
    FROM
        dba_temp_files
    GROUP
    BY  tablespace_name
       ) ts ON t.tablespace_name = ts.tablespace_name
LEFT
JOIN   (SELECT  tablespace_name,
        MAX(bytes)/1024/1024 AS largest,
        MIN(bytes)/1024/1024 AS smallest,
        COUNT(bytes) AS fragments,
        SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 AS free_space,
        ROUND(AVG(bytes))/1024/1024 AS average
    FROM
        dba_free_space
    GROUP
    BY  tablespace_name
    UNION
    SELECT  tu.tablespace,
        0 AS largest,
        0 AS smallest,
        0 AS fragments,
        SUM(tu.blocks * ts.block_size)/1048576 AS free_space,
        0 AS average
    FROM
        v$tempseg_usage tu
    LEFT
    JOIN    dba_tablespaces ts ON tu.tablespace = ts.tablespace_name
    GROUP
    BY  tu.tablespace   
       ) te ON t.tablespace_name = te.tablespace_name
ORDER
BY  t.tablespace_name
/
```

It works for both 10g and 11g.

Comment: thanks for info, if there is some way not impacting the performance of the DB?

Comment: This script won't impact performance as it will take a few seconds to run at most.  Whatever you use to see this information will need to collect it from the database.